# Remove nested table border from itext table

Tags: java, itext7

I was trying to create nested table in itext by java. I can create it but unexpectedly, the nested table holds its own border along with the original table's cell border.
Is there any way to **remove the outer border only of the nested** table, in **nestedParent's** right column?
[image: my generated pdf format]
My code:

```
String dest= FileSystems.getDefault().getPath("").toAbsolutePath().toString()+"/test.pdf";
        log.info(dest);
        PdfWriter writer= new PdfWriter(dest);
        PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(writer);
        pdfDoc.addNewPage();

        Document document = new Document(pdfDoc);

        float [] pointColumnWidths = {150F, 150F};
        Table outerTable = new Table(pointColumnWidths);

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            outerTable.addCell("col1-" + i);
            outerTable.addCell("col2-" + i);

        }

        float [] innerTablePointColumnWidths = {150F, 150F, 150F, 150F};
        Table nestedTable = new Table(innerTablePointColumnWidths);

        nestedTable.addCell("col11");
        nestedTable.addCell("col11_val");

        nestedTable.addCell("col12");
        nestedTable.addCell("col12_val");

        nestedTable.addCell("col22");
        nestedTable.addCell("col22_val");

        nestedTable.addCell("col23");
        nestedTable.addCell("col23_val");

        nestedTable.addCell("col31");
        nestedTable.addCell("col31_val");

        nestedTable.addCell("col32");
        nestedTable.addCell("col32_val");

        outerTable.addCell("nestedParent");

        outerTable.setBorder(Border.NO_BORDER);
       /* Cell cell = new Cell();
        cell.add(nestedTable);*/
        // cell.setBorder(Border.NO_BORDER);
        //outerTable.addCell(cell);

        outerTable.addCell(nestedTable);



        document.add(outerTable);

        document.close();
```

**itext related lib version 7.1.12**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't solve the problem using inner table. So, to solve that, I have to define a table of 5 columns and then when necessary I have defined the necessary cell definition for that particular entry, using `row` and `col` `span`, like

```
Cell cell= new Cell(1,1);
Cell cell=new Cell(1,4);
```

For five columns inside a row:

```
Cell cell= new Cell(4,1)
```

this way it is solved!

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove each border from the inner table cells (i.e "col11" cell should set his upper and left border to null or Border#NO_BORDER AND set the inner table cell to null as well).

Furthermore, You should set the padding of the inner table to 0 in order to remove the gap.

```
Cell cell = new Cell();
        cell.setPadding(0);
        cell.add(nestedTable);
        outerTable.addCell(cell);
```

Comment: can you add code of that , extending my code given in the question please?

Comment: `nestedTable.setPadding(-1);nestedTable.addCell("col11").setBorderLeft(Border.NO_BORDER);` I changed this way, inner table's right border gets aligned with the outer one[for padding] but others are as they were

Comment: I solved it in another convenient way[in my answer]. Thanks for your effort